# Retrieving ecommerce transaction IDs from a Multi-Channel Funnel API call

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am using the Top Conversion Paths report,  with Campaign Path as the primary dimension and filtered to only use ecommerce transactions and only include entries with a certain campaign in them to gauge the impact of an advertising partner.

This gives me the number of transactions and the value - what I would also like are the transaction IDs.

I cannot seem to find a way of getting these IDs using the google analytics API. Has anyone else been able to do this?

I am using Universal Analytics.

Many thanks.

Edited to add:

Currently I'm using the core API to return a list of ga:transactionids etc for a ga:campaign - like this:

```
$optParams1 = array(

    'dimensions' => 'ga:transactionId',
    'metrics' => "ga:transactionRevenue,ga:transactionTax,ga:transactionShipping,ga:itemQuantity",
    'sort' => '-ga:transactionId',
    'segment' => "gaid::xxxx",
    'filters' => 'ga:campaign==' . $campaign,
    'max-results' => '10000'

);
```

Problem is the core reporting stuff is last-click based only. The MCF stuff gives me a better picture of what's working: but it doesn't return ga:transactionids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transactionId is not available in MultiChannelFunnels. Here's a list of all supported metrics/dimensions:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/mcf/dimsmets/conversionpaths

That is available in the Core Reporting API though.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=ecommerce&jump=ga_transactionid

But the reports you can do there are quite different so I'm not sure if this will suffice. You haven't made clear exactly what kind of report you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks Eduardo. I'm using the core API to return a list of ga:transactionids etc for a ga:campaign - like this:

    $optParams1 = array(

        'dimensions' => 'ga:transactionId',
        'metrics' => "ga:transactionRevenue,ga:transactionTax,ga:transactionShipping,ga:itemQuantity",
        'sort' => '-ga:transactionId',
        'segment' => "gaid::xxxx",
        'filters' => 'ga:campaign==' . $campaign,
        'max-results' => '10000'

    );

Problem is the core reporting stuff is last-click based only. The MCF stuff gives me a better picture of what's working: but don't have trans IDs.

Answer (score 1):

You can get some of that functionality you are looking for by querying what you would in the MCF query in a segment, and then put the transactionId in the dimensions via the core reporting.

Your segment would looks something like this:

```
users::condition::ga:campaign=@yourcampaigntag
```

Then even if the transactions occurred later with a different campaign tag last-click, you still can retrieve those if them.

Let me know if you were able to solve this in another way.